# Using openmp with odeint

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I am trying to use openmp to parallelize my code using odeint and openmp, but when I change the number of threads, the parallelism don't work, the time to finalize the execution does not improve. What I am doing wrong?

Here are the essential parts of the code :

```
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;
using namespace std;
typedef std::vector< double > state_type;

struct ode {
  void operator()( const state_type &XY , state_type &dUdt , double t ) {

    const size_t N = XY.size();

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(runtime)
    for (size_t aux = 0; aux <= N; aux++) {

      dUdt[0] = XY[1];
      dUdt[1] = 2 * w * XY[3] + 3 * (w * w) * XY[0];

    }
  }
};

main() {

  typedef runge_kutta4<
              state_type , double ,
              state_type , double ,
              openmp_range_algebra
            > rk4;

  state_type XY(2);

  int number_threads = 1;

  omp_set_num_threads(number_threads);
  int chunk_size = omp_get_max_threads();
  omp_set_schedule( omp_sched_static , chunk_size );

  integrate_n_steps( rk4() , ode() , XY , 0.0 , 0.00001 , 200);  

}
```

I hope I have been clear enough, I just would like to be able to use openMP with my code.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `aux` variable is not used in that for-loop, maybe compiler / runtime is smart enough to notice that (although there should be a warning?), and doesn't parallelize anything. Do compiler options include `-fopenmp`?

Answer (score 0):

Your state has size 2. This is way too small to expect any improvement from parallelizing. Try an example with like ~1000 variables and see if you find some improvement...

Comment: I tried it, but don't work. When I call the method omp_get_num_threads() inside of the observer function I see that the number of threads is aways 1. I don'y understand what I am doing wrong. There is someway of change it?

Comment: The observer is not parallelized automatically. Calling omp_get_num_threads() will only work inside a parallel region